# What's wrong with my implementation of the Matching Pursuit algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithms, approximation

I have recently attempted to implement a simple version of the Matching Pursuit algorithm, following the description detailed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_pursuit#The_algorithm). Although the algorithm itself seems dead simple, my implementation produces very suboptimal results in some cases (i.e. the inner product between the represented signal and the sparse reconstruction is very small).

Here is the Python function I have written, `x` is the input signal and `D` is the dictionary matrix with normalized rows.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la

def matching_pursuit(x: np.ndarray,
                     D: np.ndarray,
                     eps_min: np.float64 = 1e-3,
                     iter_max: int = 1000) -> np.ndarray:
    
    s = np.zeros(D.shape[0], dtype=np.float64)
    
    r = x.astype(np.float64)
    for _ in range(iter_max):
        dot = np.dot(D, r)
        i = np.argmax(np.abs(dot))
        
        s[i] = dot[i]
        r -= s[i] * D[i, :]
        
        if la.norm(r) < eps_min:
            break
        
    return s
```

As an example, for a randomly generated matrix D equal to:

```
[[0.09365858 0.65561007 0.74926865]
 [0.24806947 0.62017367 0.74420841]
 [0.08804509 0.70436073 0.70436073]
 [0.54545455 0.54545455 0.63636364]
 [0.62469505 0.46852129 0.62469505]
 [0.68100522 0.59587957 0.42562827]
 [0.64465837 0.72524067 0.24174689]
 [0.24077171 0.48154341 0.84270097]
 [0.58834841 0.19611614 0.78446454]
 [0.80178373 0.26726124 0.53452248]
 [0.45584231 0.56980288 0.68376346]
 [0.36214298 0.81482171 0.45267873]
 [0.19802951 0.69310328 0.69310328]
 [0.74535599 0.59628479 0.2981424 ]
 [0.76249285 0.45749571 0.45749571]
 [0.19802951 0.69310328 0.69310328]
 [0.46829291 0.74926865 0.46829291]
 [0.70014004 0.14002801 0.70014004]
 [0.76626103 0.28734789 0.57469577]
 [0.93704257 0.31234752 0.15617376]]
```

and an input signal `x = [1, 2, 3]` the function returns

```
[ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.00119178 -0.00095663 -0.00167583  0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.        ]
```

which results, when multiplied with the dictionary matrix again, in
`x = [-4.48011162e-04,  7.50118419e-05, -1.83267255e-03]`.

Now what I'm wondering is whether I have made some mistake in my implementation or whether this is an expected outcome due to the nature of the algorithm and/or properties
of these specific sample inputs.

Comment: Where did your data come from? did you just randomize it?

Comment: Yes, I just used `np.random.randint` to create `D`.

Comment: It is difficult to folllow your program without having the main part. However, the approximation of $x$ is equal to $\sum_i s_i D_i$. It does not seem to be provided by the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MP it is very important which dictionary is used. For example, if the atoms are orthogonal The problem will converge faster.

Another interesting example, where two entries of the dictionary are the same, you can wither find both corresponding values in the sparse signal as 1 and zeros or as 0.5 and 0.5. You can find any number of representation for such an example. Which one will the algorithm converge to?

In general, the picking of the dictionary $D$ is a very important point in the MP algorithm. I recommend you take a look in [the following link](https://scialert.net/fulltext/?doi=jai.2018.1.8) as well as researching a bit more yourself. The Fourier matrix, for example, is a common choice for the dictionary.

To answer your question, while I could not find a problem with your implementation of the algorithm, the data you are using might be problematic.

Comment: Okay, I had just assumed that even with a random dictionary the algorithm would converge to an okay-ish solution but I'll take a look at the article you posted, thanks.